# Using TSOP53456 IR receiver module to detect the presence of IR light

Tags: esp32, infrared, ir-receiver

I'm doing a project using two ESP32-C3 microcontrollers and some IR LEDs and IR receivers to make a solution that would let me measure the time it takes someone to run some X distance.

It works by having two station. A station is comprised of an ESP32-C3 microcontroller that's connected with an IR LED and an IR receiver. The IR LED shines IR light to an IR reflective material that would be placed about a meter in front of the IR LED. The light would then be reflected back into an IR receiver which is also connected to the ESP32-C3. What I'm trying to do is create a beam of IR light between the two sides, that would break when something passed through between those two sides. That would trigger the counter that would measure the amount of time that has passed since that first trigger, and the trigger that would occur when that something passes through the other station, that would be X meters ahead.

**PROBLEM:**

Since this is my first electronics project of this caliber, I have no idea how to use the IR reciever I have, and can an IR reciever even be used in this scenario? I don't need to send any data using IR light, I just need to make a beam. I need to pulse IR light, I don't know, about 1 kHz, and using the IR reciever, measure if any interruptions happen that would trigger the counter.

Exact model of the IR reciever is: Vishay electronics TSOP53456.
The IR LEDs I have are this low-power one SIR-34ST3F and a high-power one VSLY5850.

Finally, to be really specific, how to wire the IR reciever, and what would I need to do in terms of code to be able to do what I described above?

**EDIT:**

I found this active IR sensor [TCRT5000](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf) that's an IR LED and a phototransistor in one. I was wondering if I could use this in my project to simplify manners? Does it work in a way that would make it suitable in my use-case?

Comment: You use the IR receiver as explained and shown in the data sheet. Do you have a specific question about using the IR receiver module?

Comment: @Justme I wasn't really clear in my post. I found out that IR receiver and IR sensors aren't the same thing. IR receiver is used for demodulating signal and forwarding it to a microcontroller for processing. What I needed for my project is a simple IR sensor for detection of IR light. I was wondering if I can use this IR receiver I have for that purpose? The datasheet doesn't contain much information about this.

Comment: Have you considered that the runner who breaks the beam may act as a beam-reflector himself/herself instead of the intended retro-reflector?

Comment: @glen_geek I didn't. Do you think that would work? Would the runner have to wear something that's IR reflective, and if not, how sensitive would the IR sensor have to be to pick up something like that?

Comment: Yes the module can be used. You just need to send the IR as per the module requirements. Common mistakes include sending IR in a way that the module filters it away.

Comment: Agree with @Justme : SIR-34ST3F IRled, combined with TSOP53456 IRreceiver can work over a 1-2 m distance. I'd suggest not using a retro-reflector sheet (*have made that work* but its tricky). Yes, the modulation scheme of TSOP53456 requires some effort, but is well-within the capabilities of ESP32. Timing resolution is limited to a few milliseconds. A TCRT5000 is meant for very short distance use - extremely difficult to extend range to 1m...not appropriate.

Comment: I've found this component that uses ultrasonic sound to measure distance to something passing in front of it. https://handsontec.com/index.php/product/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-ranging-module/  I wouldn't need to use anything retro-reflective to trigger the counter so it simplifies everything. What do you think? The range is 2cm-400cm.